# QtCreator project to remote GIT repository

Tags: git, qt-creator

Trying to create hello world application with `QtCreator` and place it to `BitBucket` server. In order to do that I create repository `BitBucket` `git@bitbucket.org:qt/aaa.git`. Then I have created `Qt` project `aaa` that is located in `~/project/aaa` and in wizard I have selected GIT.

Is my approach correct? What actions I should perform in order to connect my project with remote repository. Can I use `QtCreator` for this reason or I should go to console?

Comment: I spent like half an hour trying to make Git work in Qt Creator, I'm just using console now. But that's because I didn't research enough I guess.

Comment: I'm using SmartGit for the same reason

Comment: Usually you first clone your remote git repo locally and then create your local files/project in that local repo and commit. I don't if it's easy to do in QtCreator but to init/clone is just done once, after that you can do the git-commit etc in QtCreator when developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do like this

1) Create a BitBucket repository and get the https link of that BitBucket server. Usually it is in the format https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/username/rep-name.git

2) Open git console in your local project folder and initialise it. Use command

```
git init
```

3) If you have not set user name and email, set it using commands:

```
git config --global user.name "Username "
git config --global user.email 'emailid'
```

4) Now add remote rep by

```
git remote add origin rep_link
```

5) Now push your rep to remote by

```
git push -u origin master
```

After doing this in qt creator you can use other commands like push pull commit etc. If git is not showing in qt creator go to tools>options>version control>git> add "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" without quotes in prepend to path under configuration assuming you have installed git in the above location